# What are the typings for multi-page or multi-step formik form with React Hooks?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, formik, react-typescript, react-forms

I have a base component with `<form>`

BaseForm.tsx

```
import React from 'react'
import { useFormik } from 'formik';

export default function BaseForm() {

  const formik = useFormik({
    initialValues,
    validationSchema,
    onSubmit: values => console.log(values),
  });


  return (
    <div>
      <form onSubmit={formik.handleSubmit}>
        <PageOne formik={formik} />
        <PageTwo formik={formik} />
      </form>
    </div>
  )
}
```

And PageOne.tsx

```
import React from 'react'

export default function PageOne({ formik }: any) {
  
  return (
    <div>
      Page One Form Controls...
    </div>
  )
}
```

And similarly PageTwo.tsx

Now, in the PageOne `props`, what are the Typings that we should add?

I tried with `PageOne({ formik }: FormikProps<PageOneForm>)` but not working.

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```js
PageOne({ formik }: { formik: FormikConfig<PageOneForm> })
```

**If** `PageOneForm` are the values of `initialValues`.

I always prefer to extract the args types into an interface.

```js
import React from 'react'
import { FormikConfig } from 'formik'

interface IProps {
  formik: FormikConfig<any>; // expected form values instead of any
}

export default function PageOne(props: IProps) {
  const { formik } = props;
  
  return (
    <div>
      Page One Form Controls...
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: By doing so, getting this error

Property 'values' does not exist on type 'FormikConfig<PageOneForm>'
Property 'setFieldValue' does not exist on type 'FormikConfig<PageOneForm>'

Here `PageOneForm` is an interface of form controls